# my login info for.net app didnt get recorded using UFT

Tags: .net, automation, uft14

While i run the the recorder on UFT and log iN to.net app. I dont see any script for the LogIn info that i entered .

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe","","C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application",""
SystemUtil.Run "C:\Users\Halmahri\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Google Chrome.lnk","","",""

Browser("Browser").Navigate "https://admissionsupportstg.moe.gov.sa/"

Browser("Browser").Page("قبول - اختيارات دراسية").Link("دخول").Click

Browser("Browser").Page("تسجيل الدخول عبر اسم مستخدم").WebButton("دخول").Click
```